# Rails Beginner: I want to create a callback in one model that can create a new entry in another model/table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activerecord

I'm new to rails. What I have is a model semester and a model teacher. Can I create a callback, before_create/after_create in one model to add an entry in another model ?

Comment: Kindly if you can refer any example or any external link to guide me. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Callback in one model can create/update/destroy another model.

As an example you can look callbacks `after_create` and `after_destroy` in popular (33.5K star) project [discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/dc6b547ed89f652b5406489d76140b76cf8e0d1d/app/models/topic_tag.rb#L7)